# Why are references in a list lost in this threaded program?

Tags: c#, object, memory, reference

I'm writing a program in C#, which must be executed as a service.

In my main class, I have object1 of class1 and a Thread t, and I instantiate object1 and use the thread t to run the method "run" of this object on the onStart method of this main class (object1 is a class variable).  In the method onStop, I call the stop() method of object1.

In class1 I have a list, and in the method run() of class1 I add an element to the list (I've checked it gets added). In the method stop() I try to retrieve this element, but the list has no elements.

```
partial class ServiceClass: ServiceBase
{
    volatile Class1 object1 = new Class1();
    volatile Thread t = null;

    public ServiceClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            t = new Thread(object1.run);
            t.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            t.Join();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        object1.Stop();
        t.Join();
    }
}

class Class1
{
    private List<FileProcessor> fileProcessors = new List<FileProcessor>();
    private FileSystemWatcher awatcher = null;

    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public void run()
    {
        FileProcessor fp = new FileProcessor();
        fileProcessors.Add(fp);

        awatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Example", "*.csv");
        awatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        awatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(awatcher_Created); 
        awatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(awatcher_Renamed);
        awatcher.InternalBufferSize = 4096 * 500;
        awatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        foreach (FileProcessor fileProcessor in this.fileProcessors)
        {
            if (fileProcessor != null)
            {
                fileProcessor.Stop();
            }
        }

        if (awatcher != null)
        {
            awatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            awatcher.Dispose();
        }
        Environment.Exit(-2);
    }

    void awatcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldName.Replace(".prepare", "").Equals(e.Name) && e.Name.EndsWith(".csv") && !e.Name.Contains(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestParameter"]))
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            awatcher_Created(sender, new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, fi.DirectoryName, e.Name));
        }
    }

    void awatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Nothing yet
    }


}
```

When the Stop() function gets called, awatcher is null and the list is empty, as if it run hadn't been called.  Why does this reference get lost?

Edit: If I declare those variables as static, it works right. However, I'd prefer to use non-static variables.

Comment: Could you work this into some bare bones sample code?  It makes it much easier for people to help.

Comment: Can you show us your code?  There are lots of reasons this could happen.  Perhaps your list is stored in a static variable and thus needs to be declared [volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx).  Perhaps your list is being accessed concurrently so you need a [thread safe collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `object1`, `class1`... seriously? You don't event name your classes/variables properly and you're messing with threading? Did you know a `List<T>` isn't thread-safe? Show your code so we can help

Comment: post your code. We are not magician.

Comment: You never started the thread (t.Start();)  unless that is happening in callMonitor.Start();?

Comment: Sorry, it had the wrong name, callMonitor is t indeed, but i changed the names for the sample

Comment: Have you tried debugging? You should create a normal winforms application that calls Start and Stop from two buttons, then you can easily debug your service code.

Comment: Yes, I have. When running through the run method, I can see how the element is added to the list and how the awatcher variable has a value. After that, inside the stop method, the list is empty and awatcher is null.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have tried to recreate your scenario. [Here it is as a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D9pjtF). Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce the missing list item.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyMainClass
{
    public static Class1 object1 = new Class1();
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mimic a service's OnStart and OnStop");
        OnStart();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
        Console.ReadLine();
        OnStop();
    }

    public static void OnStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(object1.Run));
        t.Start();
    }

    public static void OnStop()
    {
        object1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public List<object> list = new List<object>();
    public void Run()
    {
        list.Add("Some Element");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I speculated as a way to encourage a newbie and to demonstrate a bare bones example. Also, I have nothing better to do right now. :-)